Magento 2 : when i am trying to use GetSalableQuantityDataBySku it will give me an error
I am new in magento. When I am trying to use GetSalableQuantityDataBySku" does not exist
magento throw me an error below error
i am use
event which i use : <event name="sales_order_place_after">
use Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku;

protected $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;

   GetSalableQuantityDataBySku                                    $getSalableQuantityDataBySku,

 $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku = $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;




Are you using MSI or not?

how we can check that thing i have no idea how we can check i am new in magento development

Paste the full constructor code of your class

namespace Vendor\Module\ModelName;
use Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku;
class ClassName
{
    private $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;
    public function __construct(
        GetSalableQuantityDataBySku $getSalableQuantityDataBySku
    ) {
        $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku = $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $sku = "testsku"; //pass your product sku
        $salable = $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku->execute($sku);
        echo json_encode($salable);
    }
}

